# Most pythonic way to get tmp folderpath?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder structure like:

```
myproj
   |
   |
   +-- tmp
   |
   +-- my_proj
   |      |    
   |      +-- config.py
   |      | 
   |      +-- package_1
   |      |      | 
   |      |      +-- __init__.py
   |      |      |  
   |      |      +-- data_maker.py  
   |      | 
   |      | 
   |      +-- package_2
   |             | 
   |             +-- __init__.py
   |             | 
   |             +-- hello_world.py  
   |       
   |       
   |
   +--README.md
   |           
   |
   +--setup.py
```

`data_maker.py` makes a bunch of temporary files in the process of its running and deposits those files to `myproj\tmp`. What is the most pythonic way to reference the `myproj/tmp` forlderpath?

My current solution is to have this inside of `data_maker.py`:

```
import os
tmp_folder = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))), 'tmp')
```

which seems extremely ugly and in python. Should I put something into the `config.py` that specifies the tmp folder? or maybe build a class that can get all the directories?

Comment: Other than the fact that you don't need two `dirname`s, it's pretty close to optimal, AFAIK. `tf = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "tmp")` would be slightly more concise.

Comment: @gilesc, based on the location of `data_maker.py`, it needs three `dirname` calls.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You could substitute with `myproj.__file__` (which would also safeguard you against if you moved `data_maker.py` later). I usually approach this sort of thing by first getting my project root.